# how to fix startWith not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I am checking some date whether available or not from DB using Ajax using below my code,

```
 var url = "ValidateDateFromDB.jsp?cdate="+selecteddate.value;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange =callback;
    req.send(null);


 function callback()
    {
      if (req.readyState == 4)
       {
        if (req.status == 200) 
          {
              var message = req.responseText;
              alert(message);  
              if(message.startsWith("Available"))
                {
                   alert("Availabe");

                }
               else
                {
                   alert("Not Availabe");
                }


          }
        }
     }
```

I am getting output like below image,

[image]

It is working fine in firefox but not working in chrome.I checked out that startsWith works only chrome above 40 version.So to fix this i used `==` operation like below,

```
if(message=="Available")
    {
      alert("Availabe");

    }
else
   {
     alert("Not Availabe");
   }
```

But this code always goes to else part that i know why.

someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: `if(message.indexOf("Available")==0)` should be equivalent to `message.startsWith("Available")`, or you could use the polyfill from MDN to use `String.prototype.startsWith`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: You are right @pawel.Its working also in chrome.Thank you.